C++17 Lookup table with a tuple. I need a compile time error if given value was not found
I have a table with two typed values. In the productive code I search a given value in the tuple. What I do not get Is if the value is not found in the tuple I want to get a compile time error. Example below:
I have this function:
template <typename TLookup, typename TValueToSearch, typename TSetting>
constexpr auto lookupNeededSetting(const TValueToSearch &valueToSearch)
{
  TSetting setting = {};
  typename TLookup::Type const table = typename TLookup::Type{};

  std::apply(
      [&valueToSearch, &setting](const auto &...entry) {
        // Iterate over each entry in the table
        return (((entry.fits(valueToSearch)) ? setting = entry.value() : false) || ...);
      },
      table);

  return setting;
}

this searches a given table like this:
template <typename... TEntries>
struct LookupTable
{
  using Type = std::tuple<TEntries...>; ///< Type representing the tuple of entries.
};

The given entries have a function fits which checks if the given value is the same one, if yes it returns the translated value. What does not work is, if the given value was not in the table I want to have a compile time error, but I do not get it to work. Is this possible?
its used like this:
using TestValueLookup = LookupTable<Entry<TypedValue<uint16_t, 1>, TypedValue<uint8_t, 0x00>>,
                                    Entry<TypedValue<uint16_t, 2>, TypedValue<uint8_t, 0x01>>,
                                    Entry<TypedValue<uint16_t, 3>, TypedValue<uint8_t, 0x02>>,
                                    Entry<TypedValue<uint16_t, 4>, TypedValue<uint8_t, 0x03>>>;

constexpr auto settingValue = utilities::lookupNeededSetting<TestValueLookup, uint16_t, uint8_t>(1);

New Example:
template <typename TLookup, typename TValueToSearch, typename TSetting, auto VValueToSearch>
constexpr bool lookupNeededSetting2(TSetting& setting) {
    bool found = false;
    typename TLookup::Type const table = typename TLookup::Type{};

    std::apply(
        [&found, &setting](const auto&... entry) {
            // Iterate over each entry in the table
            ((entry.fits(VValueToSearch) ? (setting = entry.value(), found = true) : false) || ...);
        },
        table);

    return found;
}

template <typename TLookup, typename TValueToSearch, typename TSetting, auto VValueToSearch>
class Lookup {
public:
    static constexpr TSetting setting = [] {
        TSetting tempSetting{};
        constexpr bool found = lookupNeededSetting2<TLookup, TValueToSearch, TSetting, VValueToSearch>(tempSetting);
        static_assert(found, "The given VValueToSearch was not found in the lookup table.");
        return tempSetting;
    }();

    static constexpr auto value = setting;
};

unfortunately the compiler complains about tempSetting that it is not constant

You are passing a run-time parameter to lookupNeededSetting; there's no way to detect a missing value at compile time. utilities::lookupNeededSetting<TestValueLookup, uint16_t, uint8_t, 1>::value could be made to work. Probably utilities::lookupNeededSetting<TestValueLookup, 1>::value too. The point is that the lookup key should be a template parameter, just like the entries in the lookup table.

Ok first thanks for the answer. I will give your proposal a try.

Just to mention that the value I give to lookupNeededSettings is given at compile time not at runtime.

You can use static_assert for triggering compile-time errors. Try putting it in lookupNeededSetting() if the search doesn't find anything. The first parameter is a boolean, the second is optional and can be an error message written by you.

I tried now several things but im not pretty sure how to do it.

I updated with a new example

My Solution for now is this:
template <typename TSetting>
class Setting
{
public:
  bool m_found = false;
  TSetting m_value;
};

template <typename TLookup, typename TValueToSearch, typename TSetting, auto VValueToSearch>
constexpr Setting<TSetting> lookupNeededSetting2()
{
  Setting<TSetting> setting{};
  typename TLookup::Type const table = typename TLookup::Type{};

  std::apply(
      [&setting](const auto &...entry) {
        // Iterate over each entry in the table
        ((entry.fits(VValueToSearch) ? (setting.m_value = entry.value(), setting.m_found = true) : false) || ...);
      },
      table);

  return setting;
}

template <typename TLookup, typename TValueToSearch, typename TSetting, auto VValueToSearch>
class Lookup
{
public:
  static constexpr auto getSetting = [] {
    return lookupNeededSetting2<TLookup, TValueToSearch, TSetting, VValueToSearch>();
  }();

  static constexpr auto setting = getSetting;

  static_assert(setting.m_found, "Your searched setting was not found.");
};

